# Converting date from 2019-07-04 14:01 +0000 to MM/dd/yyyy format

Tags: r, date-conversion

I am trying to the date format `2019-07-04 14:01 +0000` to `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

I am using this:

```
as.Date(strptime(d <- Twitter$time, "%b %d %Y %H:%M %p"))
```

I've also tried:

```
ymd_hms(Twitter$time)
```

However it returns NA values. Is there any way to convert this format to `MM/dd/yyyy` in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we are not interested in the time component convert the column to `Date` class with `as.Date` (here the `format` is not required as the input is in the default format mode) and use `format` to change the format

```
format(as.Date(str1), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "07/04/2019"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2019-07-04 14:01 +0000"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are always *two* steps: *parse*, and *format*.

You can use `as.Date()` as shown or  `anydate()` from the [`anytime`](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package (which will also work for different input formats as shown here):

```
R> inp <- anytime::anydate(c("2019-07-04 14:01 +0000", "04-Jul-2019 14:02"))
R> inp
[1] "2019-07-04" "2019-07-04"
R> format(inp, "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "07/04/2019" "07/04/2019"
R>
```